# when using Microsoft.Devices.Radio class in my windows phone application will the radio play in background?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, fm-radio

i am using the radio class in my application

```
FMRadio myRadio = FMRadio.Instance;

            // Turn the radio on.
            myRadio.PowerMode = RadioPowerMode.On;
            myRadio.CurrentRegion = RadioRegion.Europe;

            // Set the frequency.
            myRadio.Frequency = 92.7;
```

will the application exit and the radio of my phone will appear or will it play in background??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will play on the background when you exit your app.